# SQL - find which product is selling faster in which store query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a table where all sales are recorded for all branches. I need to figure out which store is selling which product faster than others so that we can decide which inventory to send to which store

Sample DATA:

```
Ref    | Colour | Size | Branch | QtySold | DatePosted
012345 | BLU    | 01   | ABC    | 1       | 2016-08-01 17:37:29.310 
012345 | BLU    | 01   | CFR    | 1       | 2016-08-01 17:37:29.310
012345 | BLU    | 01   | CFD    | 2       | 2016-08-01 17:37:29.310
021456 | YEL    | 06   | ABC    | 5       | 2016-08-02 17:37:29.310
021456 | YEL    | 06   | AMC    | 2       | 2016-08-02 15:37:29.310
```

I wrote following SP which accepts FromDate and ToDate and other parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesByDate] 
(
  @FromDate datetime = NULL, 
  @ToDate datetime = NULL,
  @Ref nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
  @ColourCode nvarchar(20) = NULL,
  @StoreCode nvarchar(6) = NULL,
  @SizeIndex nvarchar(3) = NULL
)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT
YEAR(S.DatePosted)  'Year', DATEPART(week,S.DatePosted ) NumberOfTheWeek,
S.Ref, 
S.Colour ColourCode, 
S.Sno SizeIndex, 
S.Branch StoreCode,
DATEDIFF(day,@FromDate, @ToDate) TotalDays,
SUM(S.Qty) QtyPerUnit

FROM SalesHistory S

WHERE 
(S.DatePosted BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
AND (S.Ref IN (SELECT * from dbo.SplitList(@Ref, ',')) OR @Ref IS null)
AND (S.Colour = @ColourCode OR @ColourCode IS null)
AND (S.Sno = @SizeIndex OR @SizeIndex IS null)

AND (S.Branch = @StoreCode OR @StoreCode IS NULL)

GROUP BY 
S.Branch, YEAR(S.DatePosted), DATEPART(week,S.DatePosted),S.Ref,S.Colour,S.Sno

ORDER BY 
S.Ref, S.Colour
```

I feel the above SP doesn't return what I want...
I want to compare the sales of each Ref,color,size(Product) in each branch

1. given the FromDate and ToDate, return the data for that period and compare it with last week and last year same week.

can anyone help here please....

Result should be something like this.

```
Year | No.OfThheWeek | Ref    | Colour | Size | Branch | TotalQtySoldForThePeriod | LastWeekTotalQtySold    | LastYearTotalQtySold
2016 |  32           | 012345 | BLU    | 01   | ABC    |    125                 |  205                      | 310
2016 |  33           | 012345 | BLU    | 01   | ABC    |    55                  |  155                      | 214
2016 |  33           | 021456 | YEL    | 06   | AMC    |    74                  |  46                       | 83
```

Comment: To start with you should define what your result should look like. Could you add a sample result to your request, please?

Comment: added the result in my question...

Answer (score 1):

First thing,you should correct your current query.
Group By so many column is alwys wrong.Group By anID column is preferable then you can join the CTE to get other column name.

AnyWay I assume your current query output is correct then you can proceed something like this.
Note :This is jut for understanding

```
declare @Reftbl table(ref varchar(20))
insert into @Reftbl
SELECT col1 from dbo.SplitList(@Ref, ',')

 declare @FromDate datetime = '2016-08-01' ,  @ToDate datetime = '2016-08-31'
 declare @lastWeekFrom datetime=dateadd(day,-7,@FromDate)
 declare @lastWeekTo datetime=dateadd(day,6,@lastWeekFrom)
 declare @lastYearSameWeekFrom datetime=dateadd(year,-1,@FromDate)
 declare @lastYearSameWeekFromTo datetime=dateadd(day,6,@lastYearSameWeekFrom)

 select @lastWeekFrom , @lastWeekTo,@lastYearSameWeekFrom,@lastYearSameWeekFromTo
 ;with CurrentCTE
 (
  SELECT
YEAR(S.DatePosted)  'Year', DATEPART(week,S.DatePosted ) NumberOfTheWeek,
S.Ref, 
S.Colour ColourCode, 
S.Sno SizeIndex, 
S.Branch StoreCode,
DATEDIFF(day,@FromDate, @ToDate) TotalDays,
SUM(S.Qty) QtyPerUnit

FROM SalesHistory S

WHERE 
(S.DatePosted BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
AND (S.Ref IN (SELECT ref from @Reftbl) OR @Ref IS null)
AND (S.Colour = @ColourCode OR @ColourCode IS null)
AND (S.Sno = @SizeIndex OR @SizeIndex IS null)

AND (S.Branch = @StoreCode OR @StoreCode IS NULL)

GROUP BY 
S.Branch, YEAR(S.DatePosted), DATEPART(week,S.DatePosted),S.Ref,S.Colour,S.Sno

--ORDER BY 
--S.Ref, S.Colour
 )
 ,LastWeekCTE
 (
   SELECT

S.Ref, 
S.Colour ColourCode, 
S.Sno SizeIndex, 
S.Branch StoreCode,
SUM(S.Qty) LastWeekTotalQtySold

FROM dbo.SalesHistory S

WHERE 
(S.DatePosted BETWEEN @lastWeekFrom AND @lastWeekTo)
AND (S.Ref IN (SELECT ref from @Reftbl) OR @Ref IS null)
AND (S.Colour = @ColourCode OR @ColourCode IS null)
AND (S.Sno = @SizeIndex OR @SizeIndex IS null)

AND (S.Branch = @StoreCode OR @StoreCode IS NULL)

GROUP BY 
S.Branch, S.Ref,S.Colour,S.Sno
 )
 ,LastYearSameWeekCTE
 (
  SELECT

S.Ref, 
S.Colour ColourCode, 
S.Sno SizeIndex, 
S.Branch StoreCode,
SUM(S.Qty) LastYearTotalQtySold

FROM dbo.SalesHistory S

WHERE 
(S.DatePosted BETWEEN @lastYearSameWeekFrom AND @lastYearSameWeekFromTo)
AND (S.Ref IN (SELECT ref from @Reftbl) OR @Ref IS null)
AND (S.Colour = @ColourCode OR @ColourCode IS null)
AND (S.Sno = @SizeIndex OR @SizeIndex IS null)

AND (S.Branch = @StoreCode OR @StoreCode IS NULL)

GROUP BY 
S.Branch, S.Ref,S.Colour,S.Sno
 )

 select c.*,c1.LastWeekTotalQtySold
 ,c2.LastYearTotalQtySold
  from 
 CurrentCTE C
 inner join 
 LastWeekCTE C1 on c.somecol=c1.somecol
 inner join LastYearSameWeekCTE c2 on c.somecol=c2.somecol
```

you can see the use of table @Reftbl.so that you do not have to use split function multiple times.

Comment: "Group By so many columns is always wrong." That's a joke, isn't it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner , No.we should really avoid group By on so many columns,if DB design permit.It is really a very shortcut approach , performance is not good.

Comment: I've never run into performance problems because of a large group by list. And I've never seen any other person having such issues. And after all there is a reason for this list; we want one result row per <list of columns>. And if that is per branch, year/week, item, color, and size, then this is the list.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner , in that case you have 4,5 ids to do so like branchid,colorid,sizeid etc.OR sometimes there is single id which represent item,color,size etc.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be in this case, however, and there exist very good databases without technical IDs, so you cannot say that grouping by many columns is always wrong. It simply isn't.

Answer (score 1):

To start with: @FromDate and @ToDate make little sense, because obviously they are supposed to be exactly one week, how else could you "compare it with last week and last year same week"? I suppose "last" means "previous" here, so we are looking at some given seven days, the previous seven days and seven days exactly a year before. So best is to ignore @ToDate and simply add 7 days to @FromDate instead in order to ensure to talk of exactly seven days.

Here is one way to do this:

```
SELECT 
  ref, colour, size, branch, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dateposted BETWEEN @FromDate 
                           AND DATEADD(day, 7, @FromDate) 
           THEN qty 
      END) AS this_week_qty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dateposted BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, @FromDate) 
                           AND DATEADD(day, -1, @FromDate)
           THEN qty 
      END) AS previous_week_qty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dateposted BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, @FromDate) 
                                   AND DATEADD(day, 7, DATEADD(year, -1, @FromDate)) 
           THEN qty 
      END) AS previous_year_week_qty
sum(qty) as sum_qty 
FROM saleshistory 
WHERE dateposted BETWEEN @FromDate 
                 AND DATEADD(day, 7, @FromDate) -- requested week
   OR dateposted BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -8, @FromDate) 
                 AND DATEADD(day, -1, @FromDate) -- previous week
   OR dateposted BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, @FromDate) 
                 AND DATEADD(day, 7, DATEADD(year, -1, @FromDate)) -- week in previous year
GROUP BY ref, colour, size, branch;
```